# On a click, show a stub or not?

Tags: navigation, web-app, browser, ajax

Consider a click event that would cause a significant change of view (e.g. going from a list of items to a detail view of a single item).  What is a better experience:

1. Switch to a stub view which shows only a spinner while the data is being retrieved
2. Show a spinner in the current view until the data is retrieved and then show the new view

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by stub view? Would it contain any content, or just space for content to load into?

Comment: @Matt Just space waiting to be populated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO the first gives the best overall impression of UI responsiveness and understanding of the user's intent, (e.g., *I've reconfigured the screen in anticipation to display the data you've requested*).  The second option could potentially be interpreted as something less favorable like *Please wait while I figure out what exactly it is you want me to do*.

In most cases, I prefer to go as far as possible with the UI and then wait.